# Hide full text or intro text from blog layout

Tags: joomla-3.x, category-blog, intro-text

How i can hide **full/intro** text from blog layout?

I chose "**Hide**" from "**Show intro text**", but it didn't work.

Joomla version 3.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option to hide intro text means hide it in the full article.

This is useful when you want to create an intro text for the category view that is different in the full view.

One method to hide the intro text from blog layout is creating an override in your template. Follow these steps:

1.- Copy file from components/com_content/views/category/tmpl/blog_item.php to templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE_NAME/html/com_content/category/blog_item.php

2.- Remove the line

```
<?php echo $this->item->introtext; ?>
```

I hope this info helps you.

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

The show intro text is meant for the article view not the blog layout. With hide intro text you can have a special intro text for your article, that can be hidden when you go to read the full article in the article view.

You can alway create template overrides to create any special layout you want.

If you search you can find many resources about creating custom layouts with template overrides.

Another option is to use article modules to display the content you want the way you want (or better each particular module provides as option).